# Is tensor product of two modules a free or a product/coproduct in a suitable category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The tensor product $A\otimes_RB$ of two modules $A,~B$ is a universal object in some category. However, I wonder is it also a **free object** or a **product** or a **coproduct** in some suitable category?

[image]

Comment: The tensor product is coproduct in the category of commutative rings.